Errors in importing MPAndroidChart: INVALID CATALOG DEFINITION
I'm trying to import MPAndroidChart in my application in android studio. This is what I did so far.
Added this in my settings.gradle.kts under repositories
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } // added this one
    }
}

Added MPAndroidChart in my dependencies.
I went to "File > Project Structures > Dependencies > Pressed the plus button here > Implementing MPAndroidChart here > OK > Apply". After all of that, I went and synced the app. However, I get this error.
INVALID TOML CATALOG DEFINITION


They also highlight this error in my build.gradle.kts

This is my first time encountering this problem so I'm lost.

Okay, the fix was simpler that what I was expecting. Apparently, capital letters are not allowed in build.gradle.kts.
To fix this, all I did was change the name to small letters.


This allowed me to successfully build my project. 
